# How to hide a custom block on checkout Magento

Tags: magento, block, checkout

I need to hide a custom block on all checkouts (onepage and cart).

How should I edit the checkout.xml to hide it?

I tried `<remove name="footer_newsletter"/>` but it doesn't work. The strange thing is that if I put `<remove name="footer" />` all the footer is hidden.

So where is the problem? On blocks section the ID and name is footer_newsletter so it's not wrong.

Comment: what is your handler and what is the name of your xml file( local.xml? )

Comment: what is the handler? I don't have a local.xml. I was making changes on checkout.xml

Comment: All layout xml files merge into one file, and some other file can override your changes

Answer (score 1):

First remove the changes you have done on checkout.xml for Add local.xml to your theme layout folder.
For example in default magento theme it would be in app/design/frontend/default/default/layout

To your theme's layout folder add `local.xml`. In this local.xml Write following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
     <checkout_cart_index>
         <reference name="footer">
              <remove name="footer_newsletter"/>
         </reference>
     </checkout_cart_index>
     <checkout_onepage_index>
         <reference name="footer">
              <remove name="footer_newsletter"/>
         </reference>
     </checkout_onepage_index>
</layout>
```

local.xml runs at the last after calling all design xml file. So it will override any changes done in any xml.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the block which you want to hide in Comment in the checkout.xml.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try something like this in `local.xml`:

```
<your_desired_handle><!-- replace handle here -->
    <reference name="parent_block_of_footer_newsletter"> <!-- replace with the name of the parent block that contains your footer_newsletter block -->
        <action method="unsetChild"><alias>alias_of_footer_newsletter_block</alias></action> <!-- replace the alias with the value of "as" attribute of your footer_newsletter block, or it's name if it does not have an "as" attribute -->
    </reference>
</your_desired_handle>
```